# Ability to use other databases in the web form module

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

We used webform-7.x-3.20 module in our web site.
But we want to connect and use a database different than Drupal's default database.

Below you can find example DB setting.

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (

  'database' => 'example_1',

  'username' => 'example_1',

  'password' => 'example_1',

  'host' => 'localhost',

  'port' => '',

  'driver' => 'mysql',

  'prefix' => 'example_',

);

$databases['default2']['default'] = array (

  'database' => 'example_2',

  'username' => 'example_2',

  'password' => 'example_2',

  'host' => 'localhost',

  'port' => '',

  'driver' => 'mysql',

  'prefix' => 'example_',

);
```

As a conlusion we want to use the second DB in webform modules. The rest will used the first DB that is default.

We could not be succesful in realizing this.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: please add more details

Comment: please add this code snippet to question (via edit) and format it as code, is can help other users to help you

Answer (score 0):

in webform module you have to use the below code

```
db_set_active('default2');
```

Comment: Thank you solvease,
But we already did this. The problem is with the webform. It does not permits to change tht DB, it gives errors:

DOException: drupal_write_record() (includes/common.inc 7196)

Comment: well you have to have the related tables in database 2 as well, otherwise in which table it will write that

Comment: Please copy the database1 to database2 and try I think it should work